# In Cocoa for OS X, What is "bundle" and what does it do?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbundle

I have known many resource are initialized with "bundle". And I know "bundle" is resource-related. But in general, I do not quite understand what **bundle** is, what it does, and what could we take it for.

Could any one answer this question for me?

Comment: this is not clear enough? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/nsbundle/info

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with Apple’s [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i).

Comment: Oh, I started with Class reference and confused. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewChang: Many of the class references, including NSBundle's, have links to relevant guides at the top of the document, under the “Companion guides” heading.